# uncompress snappy parquet files in Azure Databricks

Tags: parquet, azure-databricks, snappy

i have a bunch OF snappy parquet files in a folder in azure data lake
Does anyone have code that i can use to uncompress snappy parquet files to parquet using Azure Databricks.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The compression of Parquet files is internal to the format. You cannot simply uncompress them as with usual files that are compressed at once. In Parquet each column chunk (or actually even smaller parts of it) are compressed individually. Thus for uncompressing, you would need to read in with `spark.read.parquet` and write them out as completely new files with different Parquet settings for the write.

Note that using no compression is actually not useful in most settings. Snappy is such a CPU-efficient format that the minimal CPU time it uses is in no contrast to the benefit on time the size savings have on the transferral of the files to disk or over the network.